# CA certified .cert file on Tomcat 9 (Linux server) , tomcat command not working

Tags: ssl, java-8, keystore, tomcat9

The Keytool commands for Tomcat SSL includes self-signed certificates which doesn't work with my CA certified cert. I tried creating keystore and importing it with root, intermediate and server cert. On changing the connector port in Tomcat/conf/server.xml started tomcat server but browser URL not reflecting that URL is safe/certificate chain.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mykey.key -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile myCA.crt -caname root -chain
```

This is the command provided in Apache document, but how to import intermediate certificate in this command?

Comment: 'The Keytool commands for Tomcat SSL includes self-signed certificates': the Tomcat SSL/TLS documentation also includes what to do with CA-signed certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Meta: this isn't really a programming or development question. Plus I'm pretty sure it's partly duplicate because I remember writing most of this answer before, but I can't find it now; if I do later I will add.

First, to be clear, changing the port in a Tomcat <Connector> doesn't enable SSL/TLS (HTTPS). Enabling SSL/TLS requires changing several *other* attributes and (usually) elements in the <Connector>, and does NOT require changing the port, although you often (probably usually) do change both together.

Also, you need the intermediate cert(s) for a proper SSL/TLS server but **you *don't* need the root cert**. All SSL/TLS standards explicitly allow the server to omit the root cert from the chain transmitted in the handshake, most non-Java servers do so, and all clients I have ever seen accept it. The Java KeyStore capability was designed to support multiple applications and not just SSL/TLS, so to be safe `keytool` encourages you to include the root, but with other tools like OpenSSL it's easy to omit it. OTOH if you *want* for some reason to include it, that's permitted and does work.
(To be pedantic, it's actually the (trust) anchor not the root. Traditionally the anchor was expected to *be* the root, but over time it has developed that it *might* not. RFC8446 for TLS1.3 in 2018 is the first SSL/TLS specification to reflect this, and even there it's extremely rare, so I will ignore it.)

**Answer:** to include chain and/or root cert(s) in a PKCS12 file created with OpenSSL commandline, there are two approaches:

- manually determine the correct/desired cert(s) and supply them in *either* the `-in` option (which defaults to stdin, which in turn can be piped from e.g. `cat`) *or* `-certfile` (specifying a file containing one or more cert PEM blocks)
- specify `-chain` and provide in the working truststore *at least* the correct cert(s). OpenSSL will automatically select the cert(s) that chain from the leaf cert, ignoring any others.

  As with nearly all commandline operations, the working truststore can consist of `-CAfile` which is a file (only one) containing any number of cert PEM blocks; or `-CApath` which is a directory containing any number of files each containing one cert PEM block and with a name (or symlink) based on the subject hash, as described in the man page for `c_rehash(1)` on your system (`(1ssl)` or similar on some) or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/c_rehash.html); or both.

  If `-CAfile -CApath` are not specified, and not suppressed by `-no-CAfile -no-CApath` (in 1.1.0 up only), they default to a file and directory configured at compile time, but upstream does not supply any *contents* for such a file and/or directory. Linux distros I am familiar with all build OpenSSL to use locations in `/etc` somewhere (but they vary as to where) and have a package named something like `ca-certificates` that provides default contents for the default truststore location(s), and *may* provide a way to change those contents. For example on RedHat-family see `update-ca-trust` and on Debian-family see `update-ca-certificates`.

**Alternative:** for Tomcat 9 (and 8.5) **you don't need a keystore**. Older versions of Tomcat required you to match the SSL/TLS implementation to the configuration: Java (JSSE) required a Java keystore while 'tcnative' (aka APR = Apache Portable Runtime) required OpenSSL-style PEM files. Modern Tomcat allows you to use *either* type of configuration with *any* SSL/TLS implementation, so you can simply use `mykey.key mycert.crt intermediate.crt` in the <Connector> or better the now-preferred <SSLHostConfig> and <Certificate> sub-elements; see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support . If you are going by http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html be warned that hasn't been kept up to date and a number of details in it are wrong, although the basic ideas are mostly still valid.